# bash extended regex if statement

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

Trying to match any string that looks like `{% extends "file.txt" %}`, using the following code:

```
local FILE_REG="(\.{0,2}\/)*([a-zA-Z0-9_]*|\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)*[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]*"
local EXTENDS_REG='{%\s*extends\s*".*"\s*%}'

local extends=0
local filename="$1"

echo $EXTENDS_REG;
while read -r line ; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ "{%\s*extends\s*\".*\"\s*%}" ]] ; then
    echo "true: $line";
  else
    echo "false: $line";
  fi;
done < $filename
```

The if statement fails to return true on the first line of the following:

```
{% extends "base.tsh" %}
{% block my_block %}
  echo "Hello World from inherit.tsh!"
{% endblock %}
```

I have verified my regex on regex101.com and the pattern on line 2 matches the string perfectly, while replacing the `".*"` by  `$FILE_REG` matches the previous string with "file.txt" being replaced by any valid `/path/to/file_with_extension.txt`.

I have tried numerous variations of the EXTENDS_REG in the if statement, including:

- `if [[ "$line" =~ "$EXTENDS_REG" ]]` (variable)
- `if [[ "$line" =~ $EXTENDS_REG ]]` (variable, no quotes)
- `if [[ "$line" =~ '{%\s*extends\s*".*"\s*%}' ]]` (single quotes around regex)
- `if [[ "$line" =~ '{%\s*extends\s*"'$FILE_REG'"\s*%}' ]]` (composite + single quotes)
- `if [[ "$line" =~ {%\s*extends\s*\".*\"\s*%} ]]` (no quotes)

but none have worked. I suspect the if regex match to be too limited to read the regex properly within bash.

Anyone has any solution? Optimally I am looking for something efficient, and that does not rely on external binaries except grep, awk, sed and al. No python, ruby, perl, etc. please ;)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
line='{% extends "file.txt" %}'
if [[ $line =~ \{%[[:space:]]*extends[[:space:]]*\".*\"[[:space:]]*%\} ]]
```

In bash replace character classes such as `\s` with those of the form `[[:class:]]`.

Here's a [definitive list](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html).

Comment: Thanks, would never have found that out myself. +1 for the source too.
Would you know why using your version of the regex in a variable doesn't work? Aka `EXTEND_REG=\{%[[:space:]]*extends[[:space:]]*\".*\"[[:space:]]*%\}` and `[[ $line =~ "$EXTEND_REG" ]]` or `[[ $line =~ $EXTEND_REG ]]`? Is it because the $ conflicts with the regex eval?

Comment: Try `EXTEND_REG='\{%[[:space:]]*extends[[:space:]]*\".*\"[[:space:]]*%\}'` and then `[[ $line =~ $EXTEND_REG ]]`

Comment: It works indeed! Thanks that will allow me to make my code cleaner.